# Find $\sum_{n=0}^\infty\frac{S_n}{(n+1)!}$ if $S_n$ is the sum of the products of the first $n$ natural numbers taken two at a time

Tags: sequences-and-series, power-series

> If $S_n$ denotes the sum of the products of the first $n$ natural numbers taken two at a time, then find $$\sum_{n=0}^\infty\frac{S_n}{(n+1)!}$$

$$
S_n=\sum_{1\leq i<j\leq n} a_ia_j=\frac{1}{2}\bigg[(\sum a_i)^2-\sum a_i^2\bigg]\\
=\frac{1}{2}\bigg[\frac{n^2(n+1)^2}{4}-\frac{n(n+1)(2n+1)}{6}\bigg]$$
Then
$$\sum_{n=0}^\infty\frac{S_n}{(n+1)!}=\frac{1}{24}\bigg[\sum_{n=0}^\infty\frac{3}{(n-3)!}+\sum_{n=0}^\infty\frac{8}{(n-2)!}\bigg]\\
=T_0+T_1+T_2+\frac{1}{24}\bigg[\sum_{n=3}^\infty\frac{3}{(n-3)!}+\sum_{n=3}^\infty\frac{8}{(n-2)!}\bigg]\\
=0+0+2+\frac{1}{8}\Big[1+\frac{1}{1!}+\dots\Big]+\frac{1}{3}\Big[\frac{1}{1!}+\frac{1}{2!}+\dots\Big]\\=2+\frac{e}{8}+\frac{1}{3}\big[e-1\big]=2+\frac{11e}{24}-\frac{1}{3}=\frac{11e}{24}+\frac{5}{3}
$$

But my reference gives the solution $\frac{11e}{24}$, so what is going wrong with my attempt ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are almost correct, just pay attention to the starting index of each sum at each step:
$$\begin{align}
\sum_{n=0}^\infty\frac{S_n}{(n+1)!}&=\frac{1}{24}\sum_{n=1}^\infty\frac{3n(n+1)-2(2n+1)}{(n-1)!}\\
&=\frac{1}{24}\sum_{n=1}^\infty\frac{3(n-1)(n-2)+8(n-1)}{(n-1)!}\\
&=\frac{1}{24}\sum_{n=3}^\infty\frac{3}{(n-3)!}+\frac{1}{24}\sum_{n=2}^\infty\frac{8}{(n-2)!}\\
&=\frac{e}{8}+\frac{e}{3}=\frac{11e}{24}.
\end{align}$$

Comment: could u pls explain more on the transition of $\sum_{n=0}^\infty$ to $\sum_{n=3}^\infty$ and in which step am I going wrong ?

Comment: In your work, $T_2=8/24=1/3$. Moreover in $\sum_{n=1}^\infty\frac{3(n-1)(n-2)}{(n-1)!}$  the first term two terms are zero so it is equal to $\sum_{n=3}^\infty\frac{3(n-1)(n-2)}{(n-1)!}=\sum_{n=3}^\infty\frac{3}{(n-3)!}$